# Images for iOS and Web App

Tags: ios, web-applications, legacy

I'm developing web-application (and also native iOS app) that uses images from different websites. I can't avoid using these images, so I need to know more about copyright and authorship.

So, the question is: how can I use images from other websites legally? (these images, of course, not from photostocks or other paid-sites). Interested in fashion industry, I need to use images of clothes of famous designers. If I would declare source link to each pic, will it be ok? Or may be use "User Agreement" that tells full list of used sources?
For better understanding my question, some examples: websites - news aggregators, blogs and so on.

Comment: This is a legal question, not a programming one. Sounds like what you are wanting to do is quite different from a news aggregator. The most likely guess is you would need to explicitly license each image before you could use them... but you need to talk toa copyright lawyer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a topic that books have been written about, and law school courses taught about.  It's not something you're going to find a definitive answer for here.

Comment: I just hoped, that somebody had similar expierence. And there are so many websites that use imager from other sources, I wonder how they do it (or may be they just dont care?)

Comment: You can search the web for "fair use" -- you'll find a range of opinions and you can pick the one you believe the most.